# Unable to access module inside the django project

Tags: python, django

I have a django project like:

```
virt_env_name/
    project/
        scripts_api/
            __init__.py
            scripts/
                __init__.py
                orders.py
            api/
                __init__.py
                api.py
        project/
            settings.py
```

I am accessing the modules in `order.py` like:

```
from scripts_api.api.api import ClassA
from project.settings import Var1, Var2
```

but it is throwing the following error `No module named` for both imports.
How can I correct this?

NOTE: `scripts_api` is added in installed apps in `settings.py`. I thought it would help if scripts are in a django project application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***setting.py*** and print the value of **BASE_DIR**

Runserver and check the *terminal* if the **directory** is the same as your working directory.

Because sometimes "No Module Found" error is raised due to **BASE_DIR** not being the correct one. Usually it is one or two folder outside or inside.

In your case, printing BASE_DIR should give a value like this for you to correctly access the modules:

> abcd/pqrs/xyz/virtual_env_name/project

if the value doesn't ends the same way as above, then correct the BASE_DIR value in settings.py according to your requirement.